# Microsoft.Quantum.Oracles not found in VS Code in Azure Quantum SDK

Tags: q#, azure-quantum

My problem is that in **Visual Studio Code**, using **Azure Quantum QDK (Q#)** when I try to use **Microsoft.Quantum.Oracles**, it is not found.

---

- I have a Windows 11 machine:

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 22H2
OS build    22621.2861
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22681.1000.0
```

- I installed **VS Code**:

```
Version: 1.85.2 (user setup)
Commit: 8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681
Date: 2024-01-18T06:40:10.514Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 26354273
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

- In VS Code, installed **Azure Quantum Development Kit (QDK) v1.0.33** extension
- An easy qs file compiles and runs, but if I'd like to use **Microsoft.Quantum.Oracles**, compilation failes, although it should be available in the standard library according to
  [Microsoft Q# document about standard library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/)

```
namespace myTest {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Arrays;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Measurement;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Oracles;

    operation equalTest(elem: String, target: String) : Bool {
        return elem == target;
    }

    ...
```

```
 × name error
  ╰─▶ `Microsoft.Quantum.Oracles` not found
```

Actually, only the followings are available from Microsoft.Quantum:

- Arrays
- Cannon
- Convert
- Core
- Diagnistics
- Intrinsic
- Math
- Measurement
- Random number
- ResourceEstimation

Any idea what is missing? I spent quite some time with googling and asking Copilot without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this existing code or an example from somewhere you are trying to use?

The latest QDK is a complete re-write (see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/qsharp/announcing-v1-0-of-the-azure-quantum-development-kit/ and the prior post it references) and doesn't include all of the libraries and APIs the prior versions did.

You can see some details about language and API changes at https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp/wiki/Differences-from-the-previous-QDK#standard-library . Per the wiki, if there is a specific API you believe should be added [back], then please log an issue in the repo and provide the details.

If it is and old project or sample that you don't want to migrate yet, then you can continue to use older versions of the QDK. Though I'd recommend the latest version when possible.

p.s. Apologies for the outdated docs detailing the old APIs. We'll get those updated.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, now I understand the situation.

Comment: I have not used Classic QDK, I just started to discover Modern QDK. I just was not aware that the Modern QDK is so recent. The sample programs work, I just wanted to modify them and create new programs using documents and what I could find on the net and with the help of Copilot, but now I understand that what I found or was advised was based on the Classic QDK.

Comment: Actually, I tried to implement a more specific usage of Grover's search than the sample, which I found a bit too general in the sense that it's not obvious to me where and exactly how to implement different quantum oracles for the different search logics (e.g. searching for a specific string in an array of strings).

Comment: The approach of the online playground, and the very easy way QDK is available in VS Code is superb. Earlier I tried another quantum programming impelemtation but it was so problematic to install and set that I gave up. So it was a great pleasure to be able to try quantum coding immediately with Azure Quantum, congratulations to this.